# How to shade region under the curve in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to use matplotlib to illustrate the definite integral between two regions: x_0, and x_1.

How can I shade a region under a curve in matplotlib from x=-1, to x=1 given the following plot

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def f(t):
    return t * t

t = np.arange(-4,4,1/40.)
plt.plot(t,f(t))
```

Comment: I think fill_between will work.  t = np.arange(-4,4,1/40.) plt.plot(t,f(t)) plt.fill_between(t,f(t),color='green')

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check out [`fill`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill). Here's an [example](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.org/items/Matplotlib_SigmoidalFunctions.html) on filling a constrained region.

Comment: Here is the latest one https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html

Answer (score 80):

The final answer I came up with is to use [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html).

I thought there would have been a simple shade between type method, but this does exactly what I want.

```
section = np.arange(-1, 1, 1/20.)
plt.fill_between(section,f(section))
```

Answer (score 14):

As said before, you should use the `fill_between` function from pyplot.

And to fill the desired area under the curve, **I recommend using the `where` argument** that provide a filter that fit your data:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def f(t):
    return t * t

t = np.arange(-4,4,1/40)

#Print the curve
plt.plot(t,f(t))

#Fill under the curve
plt.fill_between(
        x= t, 
        y1= f(t), 
        where= (-1 < t)&(t < 1),
        color= "b",
        alpha= 0.2)
        
plt.show()
```

**The `where` argument accepts an array of boolean**. So you can use numpy arrays operations on boolean to make it easy. As you can see in the example, I simply used : `(-1 < t)&(t < 1)`. More details on boolean array here : [http://www.math.buffalo.edu/~badzioch/MTH337/PT/PT-boolean_numpy_arrays/PT-boolean_numpy_arrays.html](http://www.math.buffalo.edu/%7Ebadzioch/MTH337/PT/PT-boolean_numpy_arrays/PT-boolean_numpy_arrays.html)

You can play around with the parameters `alpha` (opacity) and `color` to make it look better.
Here is the desired result :

[image]

The documentation of `fill_between` is available here :
https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html