# Shade area between 2 y coordinates in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a shaded rectangle based on two vertical coordinates (the length of the rectangle should span the whole x axis).
I've tried to use `fill_between` with the following (p1 & p2 are the data coordinates):

```
f, ax1 = plt.subplots()   
x = np.linspace(200,300,2000)
y = x**(2)
y1 = x
p1 = 4700
p2 = 7700

ax1.plot(x, y, lw=2)
ax1.set_xlabel('Temperature $[K]$', fontweight='bold')
ax1.set_ylabel('Pressure $[mb]$', fontweight='bold')
ax1.fill_between(x, y1.fill(p1), y1.fill(p2))
```

But i'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

What is wrong? Any better way to do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: `y1.fill(p1)` doesn't return an array!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you mean to use [`axhspan`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axhspan_demo.html).

```
p1 = 4700
p2 = 7700
ax1.axhspan(p1, p2, color="limegreen", alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! but can I make the shaded region more transparent and in another color?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, the issue is with the use of the `.fill()` function. You can avoid that, using `fill_between` with your `x` array and just the `p1` and `p2` values, as [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) can accept scalar values for `y1` and `y2`.

```
ax1.fill_between(x, p1, p2)
```

[image]

Note, you can change the color and transparancy easily by adding a `color` and `alpha` argument:

```
ax1.fill_between(x, p1, p2, color='limegreen', alpha=0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`fill`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html) method of an array doesn't return an array, it returns `None`.

Answer (score -2):

You've misunderstood `fill_between`. When  you use it is advisable to express `y` as a function:

```
def y(x):
    return x**2
section = np.arange(start,end,0.1)
plt.fill_between(section,y(section))
```

will do the job with suitable values for `start` and `end`.

Comment: The way `fill_between` is used in the OP is correct, but `y1.fill(p1)` is `None`, not an array.

Comment: Wrong. I have used it precisely this way - it works.

Comment: This answer is correct in itself, but does not do what the question asks for because it fills the resgion between y=0 and the line defined by y=x**2. It does not produce a rectangle.

Comment: Yes, the result of a function applied over an array is an array, so the way you are using `fill_between` works but this is not pointing the problem in the OP.

Comment: This answer seems to pretty blindly copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30580669/4124317).

Comment: It wasn't copied from anywhere other than my notes contained in one of my Jupyter Notebooks. I'll happily post the notebook somewhere you suggest (It contains other things too.