# How to integrate under the curve and shade the integrated area in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve, integrate

[image]

I am using Python 3.6 (Spyder). I have a 3 column dataset (x,y1,y2). I want to integrate under the curve for the y1 vs x plot for multiple regions(like the shaded blocks that are in the linked figure): that is, x1 < x < x2 and x3 < x < x4 and x5 < x < x6 ... and I want to shade these integrated regions in different colours. Finally, I want to do the same for y2 vs x plot and shade those regions as well.

Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated.
Thank you,
AB

Comment: What have you tried to solve your problem? As you are starting in python it is recommended that you try to solve this problem.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046262/how-to-shade-region-under-the-curve-in-matplotlib